# Почему и для чего Windows хранит скриншоты?

Tags: windows

В пути "C:\Users\user.thumbnails\large" содержатся как фото с компа в маленьком разрешении, так и скрины, сделанные с окна Blender, очень много скринов с "Blender" и немного с "Chrome".
Задавая этот вопрос параллельно посмотрел инф. об этой папке, так там сказано, что эта папка для создания эскиза фото, чтобы потом быстрее их загружать. В таком случае, почему там имеются скрины с Blender? Я точно не делал этих скринов.